# How to create a cloudwatch rule for new security group creation?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-security-group, amazon-cloudtrail

I would like to create a cloudwatch rule that monitors and alerts on the creation of new security groups.  I thought that the `CreateSecurityGroup` event is what I was looking for but no metrics are being created when I create a new security group.  Below is the json for this cloudwatch rule:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateSecurityGroup"
    ]
  }
}
```

What do I need to change in order to get this working?

Comment: Side-comment: Metrics from Amazon CloudTrail can take 10+ minutes to arrive.

Comment: Its been a day since I created the rule.  I have made several security groups to test this out and have not received any metrics yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me!

Here's what I did:

- Already existing: **CloudTrail** trail running in the Region
- Went to **Amazon CloudWatch Events** in the management console
- Created a **new rule**:

  - Service: EC2
  - Event Type: API call via CloudTrail
  - Specific Operation: `CreateSecurityGroup`
  - Target: Existing SQS queue with appropriate permissions
- Created a **new Security Group** in the EC2 management console
- Went to **SQS**, found a message in the queue that was sent about a minute after the Security Group was created

Here's an extract:

```
"eventName":"CreateSecurityGroup","awsRegion":"ap-southeast-2","sourceIPAddress":"54.222.111.1","userAgent":"signin.amazonaws.com","requestParameters":{"groupName":"stackSG3","groupDescription":"trail notify","vpcId":"vpc-12347014"}
```

It took about 10 minutes for the event to appear in the CloudTrail console, but the event was CloudWatch Events rule activated within a couple of minutes.

The **event pattern** in the rule shows as:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateSecurityGroup"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm ok ill give it a try ive had mixed results with `"source": ["aws.ec2"],` I have a similar cloudwatch rule for new instance creation which only works without that.

Comment: Nope that didn't work.  The only difference is that I have it connected to an SNS instead of SQS.  Is there something I need to enable in cloudtrail to begin monitoring for this event?

Comment: Ok so it only works when a security group is created through the aws cli and does not respond when it is created through the console.